# CSS: 3 divs, one fixed sized, others dynamic with scrollable tables

Tags: html, css

I got 3 div's side by side. The leftmost div have fixed size: 60px;
The other two divs are suppose to fill the rest of the screen.
The complicated part is that the middle and right div are supposed to contain scrollable tables. As of now, I have to scroll the page to get to the bottom of the table.
Here is a picture of the current look:
[image]

As you see, I got a menu on the left sided div (the yellow border).
The two red bordered divs are tables.

Issue 1: The right-most table which contains the songs doesnt fill the rest of the screen.

Issue 2: I cant get the tables (Playlists and the table of songs) to be scrollable. In other words, I want them to 'end' at the bottom of the page and have a scrollbar inside the tables tbody or something like that.

This is the code:

```
.div_container
{
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    border: 1px solid #0000FF; /* blue */
    margin-top: 87px;
}
.div_menu
{
    width: 60px;
    background: #111111;
    position: fixed;
    float: left;
    border: 1px solid #F7FE2E; /* yellow */
}

.div_playlists
{
    width: 25%;
    height: 100%;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    margin-left: 60px;
    float: left;
    border: 1px solid #DF0101; /* red */
}

.div_tracks
{
    max-width: 60%;
    height: 100%;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 10px;
    border: 1px solid #DF0101; /* red */
}
```

And for the tables:

```
table.playlists
{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    float: left;
    background: #181818;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
    table.playlists tbody
    {
        font-size: small;
        overflow: auto;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
    }

table.tracks
{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    float: left;
    background: #181818;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
    table.tracks tbody
    {
        font-size: small;
        overflow: auto;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
    }
```

The HTML:

```
<div class="div_container">
    <div class="div_menu"></div>
    <div class="div_playlists"></div>
    <div class="div_tracks"></div>
</div>
```

Sorry for the noob question, I should probably use a bootstrap template or something, but I couldn't find any free templates that matched my design interest.

Comment: I should probably add that I use chrome, and is not interested in supporting the other browsers as of yet (its for personal use).

Comment: You could use a [jQuery plugin](http://www.fixedheadertable.com/) to scroll the table and keep the table heading displayed at all times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just a simple case of using `position:fixed`, as in [this Fiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/2k6hv/):

The CSS is the only interesting part:

```
div {
    color:white;
    position:fixed;
    overflow:auto;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    top:0;
    bottom:0;    
}
#top {
    background:red;
    height:64px;
    bottom:auto;
}
#sidebar {
    background:green;
    width:64px;
    top:64px;
    right:auto;
}
#playlists {
    background:navy;
    left:64px;
    top:64px;
    width:192px;
    right:auto;
}
#tracks {
    background:brown;
    left:256px;
    top:64px;    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

CSS

---

```
overflow-y:scroll;
```

Comment: Please explain your answer a bit. so that it can met quality requirements of Stackoverflow and OP can understand well.

Comment: sorry i just start with Stack overflow thank you for your advise